# Installing R on an unnetworked CentOS server

Tags: r, centos

I have to install R on a set of unnetworked slaves that I can SSH into from a networked master. What is the easiest way to install R on these slaves?

If the machines were networked, I would just have SSH-ed into each one, and done a:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install R
```

Comment: Can they reach the networked master, or can you only `ssh` into them? If it's the latter, you'll need to `scp` the packages & dependencies over to each node and use `rpm -ivh` to install them locally. If it's the former, you can setup your master to be a local pkg server.

Comment: @hrbrmstr How can I test the former hypothesis?

Comment: Test basic connectivity first (i.e. `ping` the master from the slaves). Next, do a `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` on the master and see if you can reach it from the slaves (`telnet`, `wget`, `curl`, `nc`, `netcat` to that port, perhaps). If that works, you can probably follow http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror to create a local mirror.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks, the local mirror seems like a viable alternative. How about when I want to install R packages with dependencies?

Comment: The least frustrating (over the long haul) way will be to [setup and maintain a CRAN mirror](http://cran.r-project.org/mirror-howto.html).